# How to get order_item_id WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to be able to get order_item_id, the unique value applied to each item in each order. This is what I have so far:

```
        global $wpdb;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items(); 
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
            $item_id = $item['item_id'];
```

The last line in the above code gets order_item_id. It normally wouldn't work but it works because I've edited get_items in class-wc-order and included:

```
        $items[ $item->order_item_id ]['item_id'] = $item->order_item_id;
```

What I want to know is how can I get order_item_id without having to edit class-wc-order. Is there any easy way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

This may be already too late for your project but may be useful for others:

```
foreach ($items as $key => $product )
```

The `$key` variable is the `item_id`you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The index/key of the array returned by `$order->get_items()` is the `order_item_id`... so try this:

```
foreach ($order_items as $order_item_id => $order_item) { 
}
```

Comment: This is saying exactly the same as [user3367143's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22200864/327074) already here. The other answer is using the `$items` variable from the question that is created using `$order->get_items()`.